# Is there any function to check value present in json array? Need where condition for in_array type json function for query

Tags: postgresql

What should I do for checking any string with json array?

I have tried query for 1st value of json array and it's working fine. Now when I tried for other value it's working wrong.

```sql
SELECT pc.product_category_id, pc.name, pc.caption,
       pca.name as main_category_name, pbg.name as product_fabric_name, 
       pc.company_id 
FROM product_category pc 
LEFT JOIN product_category pca ON pca.product_category_id = pc.main_category_id 
LEFT JOIN product_fabric_group pbg ON pbg.product_fabric_group_id = pc.product_fabric_id 
WHERE 1>0 AND (pc.company_id->>0 = '4438') 
ORDER BY pc.product_category_id DESC
```

Above query is working perfect  for company_id array is equal to { 4438, 4440, 2116, 297, 1166, 2656, 4096, 5218, 570, 1091, 1534, 649, 4182, 800, 4794, 945, 934, 4126, 2686, 4551, 3185, 4339, 1033, 1376, 1417, 5197 }

I'm getting no result found for below query :

```sql
SELECT pc.product_category_id, pc.name, pc.caption,
       pca.name as main_category_name, pbg.name as product_fabric_name,
       pc.company_id 
FROM product_category pc 
LEFT JOIN product_category pca ON pca.product_category_id = pc.main_category_id 
LEFT JOIN product_fabric_group pbg ON pbg.product_fabric_group_id = pc.product_fabric_id 
WHERE 1>0 AND (pc.company_id->>0 = '3185') 
ORDER BY pc.product_category_id DESC
```

Please suggest me query for company_id = 3185 which can result positive. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Just interesting. Why do you think that the `json(b)` array is better then the simple array (`int[]`)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the “contains” operator `@>`:

```
... WHERE pc.company_id @> '3185'
```

This query can be supported by a GIN index on the `jsonb` column.

This won't work with type `json`, only with `jsonb`. If you have `json`, you can either cast to `jsonb`:

```
... WHERE CAST(pc.company_id AS jsonb) @> '3185'
```

or (better) convert the column to `jsonb`:

```
ALTER TABLE product_category ALTER company_id TYPE jsonb;
```

Comment: You need `jsonb`, see my extended answer.

Comment: Now no error occured but still not getting expected result.

Comment: Then `pc.company_id` is not a JSON array. Tell me more if you want more help.

Comment: It is json array. I have explain all the things above. Even I attached my json array in the question. Please let me know what you want more to resolve my query.

Comment: All I can say is it works for me. Can you write a little self-contained test case that creates a table, inserts some data and then runs my query so that the result is unexpected? If you add that to the question, then mayme I can understand your problem.